# Vacuum fluorescent display: What if you power the filament (cathode) with a high voltage and the segments (anodes) with a low voltage?

Tags: high-voltage, display, vacuum-fluorescent

This question is asked because it isn't a stupid question when never be asked before. I didn't find anyone who mentioned this or even tried this.

What if you power the filament (cathode) of a VFD with a high voltage and the segments (anodes) with a low voltage? What will happen when you do this? A high voltage on the filament (with reduced current of course so it doesn't burn away) and a low (negative?) voltage (with maybe increased current) applied to the segments?

Before I try, any thoughts on this?

Comment: It is a bit hard to understand what you are in fact asking. Voltages are relative anyway, so it does not matter if you have 0V and +100V on them or -100V and 0V on them, as there will still be 100V difference.

Comment: Emitted electrons will accelerate away from the anodes, and all will be dark.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fCCkyP.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

you'll instantly fry the filaments and destroy your VFD.

If you mean this, on the other hand, with the filament at a high voltage relative to the plate:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fT1dzO.png)</sup>

Nothing of note will happen. A VFD is a vacuum tube that relies on thermionic emission, just like any other heated-cathode tube. That means the cathode has to be heated for the electrons to come off of it and move through the vacuum to the other side--unless, of course, you apply far too high a voltage, which will cause sputtering of the cathode and fairly rapid destruction of the tube.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I wrote: "A high voltage on the filament (with reduced current of course so it doesn't burn away) and a low (negative?) voltage (with maybe increased current) applied to the segments?" So I do not want to fry anything. The filament is always protected by a resistor. I did some tests with a RTMA resistance box and a lab PSU. I figured out that a higher voltage on the anode is required to ignite the anode at full brightness. On the filament the current is most important, it can be a high voltage or a low voltage, doesn't really matter. It can be powered directly.......

Comment: ... with 5v with use of a correct current limit resistor (470 ohms). This results in a lower anode voltage requirement. The anodes can be powered at 12v with use of a 220 ohm resistor. I tried to power both with 5V but the result is very weak. Lower the voltage on the filament does't help either. The anode cannot be powered lower than 8v to be useful. The filament can be powered as low as 1V with enough current. You are correct it is not possible to swap the voltages however I found out it is possible to use a lower voltage (instead of 20 or more volts).

Comment: @Codebeat If there's a resistor there, it won't be a high voltage across the filament--most of the voltage drops over the resistor.

Comment: Yeah you are right. Actually you need a (limited) current source to power the filament and a (high) voltage source to power the anode. Cathode/Filament is current driven and the anode is voltage driven. But yeah, using a resistor to limit the current is the easiest way to achieve a current limit.